# I don't want NULL and want to have values in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table employee(
    empid int,
    name varchar(5),
    salarytype varchar(10),
    salary int
)

insert into employee values (1, 'A' ,'Fixed', 500);
insert into employee values (1, 'A' ,'Variable', 300);
insert into employee values (2, 'B' ,'Fixed', 500);
insert into employee values (3, 'C' ,'Fixed', 500);`
```

```
select empid,name,  Fixed = STRING_AGG(CASE When salarytype='Fixed' then salary end,' '),
       Variable = CASE When salarytype='Variable' then salary end
From employee
group by empid,name,salarytype,salary`
```

with this query below output I am getting where empid is coming 2 times but I want only it only 1 time`

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/voYZ7.png

desired output is

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/420bB.png

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to format the data in tabular formatted `text`, or (even better) as DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix the `GROUP BY` and expressions:

```
select empid, name,
       STRING_AGG(CASE When salarytype = 'Fixed' then salary end, ' ') as fixed,
       SUM(CASE When salarytype = 'Variable' then salary end) as variable
From employee
group by empid, name
```

Comment: Without salrytype and salary in group by caluse I was getting error of "EREQUEST Column 'employee.salary' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." But here you have used SUM aggregate function and by your way it is working

Thank you:)